# Android AutoComplete text using Webservice Volley

Tags: android, web-services, autocomplete, android-volley

I am trying to implement an AutoCompleteTextView in my android project using volley library.

In my database, contains more than 2000 names. Like follows

```
-------+-----------+-------------+
id     |  name     | club_name   |
-------+-----------+-------------+
1      |  Abc      |  lions mtc  |
2      |  Gdc      |  lions mtc  |
3      |  Ytr      |  lions mtc  |
4      |  Vbf      |  lions ldc  |
5      |  Vfr      |  lions pbn  |
-------+-----------+-------------+
```

I needs to implement like when user types 3 letters, a webservice goes to the server and fetch the 10 list from the db and updates the list.

My question is

1. When user types the 4th character, again a webservice call (volley) will happen and sort the data. Is it a practical approach ?
2. I saw many tutorials / documentations regarding the dynamic autocomplete. But all are fetching data at the start of application load or static adapter method.
   Can any one leads to a documentation for my needs ?

I have tried the following static method.

```
cities=(AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.citysearch);
        String[] arr = { "Paries,France", "PA,United States","Parana,Brazil","Padua,Italy", "Pasadena,CA,United States"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arr);

        cities.setThreshold(3);
        cities.setAdapter(adapter);
```

TIA

Comment: Use a normal `Edittext`  with `TextWatcher` and a `listView` Just below it .

Comment: I am just started learning, any useful documentation ? TIA

Comment: Just search google . You will find lots of examples .Just search with keywords i have wrote above .